# Mapping a class to multiple tables

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class that can't be mapped to one explicit table. The table in which it is mapped depends on the context in which it is used. Basically it should work the same way as if I were trying to bind an `IDictionary<string, int>` to a table.

```
// this is a mapped entity, with a Guid Id, but it can't be mapped to one explicit table
public class NoTableClass : Entity<Guid>
{

}

// the table that this class gets its MyCollectionContext1 from depends on the HasMany mapping for that property
public class MappedClass1 : Entity<Guid>
{
    public IEnumerable<NoTableClass> MyCollectionContext1 { get; set; }
}

// the table that this class gets its MyCollectionContext2 from depends on the HasMany mapping for that property
public class MappedClass2 : Entity<Guid>
{
    public IEnumerable<NoTableClass> MyCollectionContext2 { get; set; }
}


// Mapping overrides

public void Override(AutoMapping<MappedClass1> mapping)
{
    mapping.HasMany(Reveal.Member<MappedClass1, IEnumerable<NoTableClass>>("MyCollectionContext1"))
        .Table("Table1")
        .Access.Field()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}

public void Override(AutoMapping<MappedClass2> mapping)
{
    mapping.HasMany(Reveal.Member<MappedClass2, IEnumerable<NoTableClass>>("MyCollectionContext2"))
        .Table("Table2")
        .Access.Field()
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}
```

It seems like NHibernate ignores the `.Table()` mapping method when the collection has a custom class. I don't understand why a dictionary of simple types can be mapped this way, but a collection with a custom class can't.

Note: I have my reasons for not wanting to use inheritance/generics to solve this problem, and not wanting to have a concrete type for each table i'm mapping to. We have a working solution using generics, but it creates other problems down the line for us.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are trying to do could be achieved with components:

```
public static void Override(AutoMapping<MappedClass1> mapping) {
    mapping.HasMany(Reveal.Member<MappedClass1, IEnumerable<NoTableClass>>("MyCollectionContext1"))
            .Component(c => {
                c.Map(x => x.Id);
                c.Map(x => x.Name);
            })
            .Table("Table1")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}

public static void Override(AutoMapping<MappedClass2> mapping) {
    mapping.HasMany(Reveal.Member<MappedClass2, IEnumerable<NoTableClass>>("MyCollectionContext2"))
            .Component(c => {
                c.Map(x => x.Id);
                c.Map(x => x.Name);
            })
            .Table("Table2")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}
```

Here is the code to play with: https://gist.github.com/4620069

Comment: That works perfectly, I've been searching for this solution for day, thanks you :) There is one issue. I don't see any way to map the primary key for `NoTableClass` so that it generates a new `Guid` with every insert. This is normally taken care of by extending `Entity<Guid>` or in the class map by using `.Id()` The only thing I can do inside of `.Component()` is `c.Map(x => x.Id)` which will just insert an empty Guid. Once i resolve this I'll accept your answer.

Comment: If all you need is `Guid` id generation then you could generate it in `NoTableClass` contrsuctor: `thid.Id = Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: We really don't want to generate the guid in code, our entire system uses Guid's as the unique identifier, and it's generated by the database when inserted, and we don't want to have one case where we generate the id in code before inserting.

Comment: In that case you should create tables `Table1` and `Table2` manually and mark `Id` column as `identity`, so the database would generate it for you.

Comment: This is an enterprise scale application, we use Guid's and we cant change the database structure. This needs to be handled by nhibernate